# Update value of Sitecore Fieldrender Control

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I have a Sitecore FieldRender control on a web page that is only displayed when the user is in Page Editor mode.  This FieldRender control displays the "raw valus" of a CheckList content item. (It is showing the pipe-delimited list of the ID's that are checked in the CheckList.)

Can I programatically update (add/remove URI values) that are displayed in the FieldRender when the user is in the Page Editor's Edit mode? I don't want to automatically write to the database because the user could always choose to click on the Close button and not save their changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like a perfect place to use an Edit Frame:

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/using-sitecore-editframe-in-pageedit/

Comment: Thanks so much! That was exactly what I needed. I had tried using   MycurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit(),  MycurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit() but could not get it to play nice with the Page Editor's Save, Save & Close, and Close buttons at the top. It always saved the changes if I clicked the Close button in the page editor regardless if I used  MycurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit() or not.